# Strings send for translation inside twig never displayed as translated

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n

I have this code inside `node.html.twig`

```
{{ 'string'|trans }}`
```

I can see the `string` and translate it inside the UI but the string is never displayed  I have also tried `{% trans %} string {% endtrans %}` and `{{ 'string'|t }}` and I have also tried using this with default **Bartik** theme.

NOTE: The site DOES show title and body translations of nodes correctly and I clear cache every time I try.

Getting the string to be translated from inside `bartik_preprocess_node`

```
$variables['transvar'] = t('new string for translation');
```

and inside `node.html.twig`

```
{{transvar}}
```

The string can be translated inside UI but still does not display translated string. Title/body are translated.

Interface and content language is detected by prefix `/LANG/node/xx` and node is displayed using `node.html.twig` with default bartik theme.

SOLUTION: Its seems that chrome was suffering from some weird caching problem.  I had restarted chrome but apparently a computer restart was all it needed.  When I restarted the problem was gone.

Comment: Can you try doing this in preprocess and send the string to twig

Comment: Yes I did update my question it seems to be something with my installation I assume

Comment: Can you kindly post the screenshot before and after clearing cache if possible?

Comment: what do you mean ? nothing changes after clearing cache just the message that cache was cleared !!!

Comment: The language of title/body (content) and `t()` (user interface) are not necessarily the same. How do you display the node and determine the language?

Comment: @4k4 added update2 is that what you are asking ?

Comment: Yes, i'm wondering how this `{% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}` from core `node.html.twig` translates then?

Comment: It seems a computer restart was in need ... do I close question or does it stay up for reference ?